# Help me understand sum involving partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, inverse-function

We have a bijective function $f$: $ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$. My textbook says:

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\partial f_i^{-1}}{\partial x_k}\cdot\frac{\partial f_k}{x_j} = \delta_{i,j}
$$

How is this derived?

Comment: NB that a bijection is not enough: you need $f$ to be a diffeomorphism for this formula to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have that 
$$(f^{-1}\circ f)(x) = x.$$

So compute
$$\frac{d}{dx_j} (f^{-1}\circ f)_i$$ 
in two ways: first, clearly
$$\frac{d}{dx_j} x_i = \delta_{ij}.$$
Second, compute the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx_j}(f^{-1}\circ f)_i = \frac{d}{dx_j} f^{-1}_i[f(x)]$$
 using the chain rule. What do you get?

Comment: Good answer, though I'll note that the $x_k$ in the first denominator is "fishy". I'd probably use $y_k$, with the understanding that the domain of $f$ is$(x_i)$, and the range is $(y_i)$. As it currently stands, the implication is that they are using $(x_i)$ as the variable in both the domain and range of $f$, which is pretty darn confusing.